# Programming strategy- how to pass objects down into a chain of classes

Tags: c#

I'm working on bettering my strategy of working with classes and objects.

What is the best way of passing an object down a through a chain of specific classes to keep the code organized.

example: working with a ZedGraph object (note) this may not be the best example but it will get the idea across.

```
class Graphhandler
{
    private ZedGraphControl ZGC;
    private SubGraphController PortionofGraph;

    public class GraphHandler(ZedGraphControl _ZGC)
    {
         ZGC = _ZGC;
         initializeGraph();
    }

    private void initializeGraph()
    {
        // notice I am putting the ZGC Object into another class
        // and likely that ZGC object will go into another class
        PortionofGraph = new SubGraphController(ZGC);
    }        
}    

class SubGraphController
{
    private ZedGraphControl ZGC;
    private DeeperSubGraphController PortionofGraph;

    public class SubGraphController(ZedGraphControl _ZGC)
    {
         ZGC = _ZGC;
         initializeSubGraph();
    }

    private void initializeSubGraph()
    {
        PortionofGraph = new DeeperSubGraphController(ZGC); 
        // is there a better way?
    }

}
```

Is there a better way of passing a yop level object down through all these calls to manipulate the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the answer is to pass fully-formed dependencies into your objects. For example:

```
public GraphHandler(SubGraphController portionOfGraph) {
     this.portionOfGraph = portionOfGraph;
}

public SubGraphController(DeeperSubGraphController portionOfGraph) {
     this.portionOfGraph = portionOfGraph;
}


...

var zedGraphControl = new ZedGraphControl();
var deeperSubGraphController = new DeeperSubGraphController(zedGraphControl);
var subGraphController = new SubGraphController(deeperSubGraphController);
var graphHandler = new GraphHandler(subGraphController);
```

Rather than constructing the `DeeperSubGraphController` directly in you subgraph controller. Nowadays, you usually orchestrate all this using a dependency injection framework.

(See also: [`Dependency Injection Myth: Reference Passing`](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/10/21/dependency-injection-myth-reference-passing/))

Comment: Yes I do agree with this, but would the approach I gave be better for simplifying the working into sub portions.  say you have 2 possible graph outcomes that require a lot of work in code for the subportions of the graph, would you then want to pass the ZGC down the chain to simply the code?

Comment: @user970011, could you give an example?

Comment: Say you have a Graph object, and with the data you have been given. you can either make the graph a line graph or a bar graph.  each graph has a large amount of code to customize the graph the way you would like.  So you create classes to handle the line graph and Bar graph work.  In order to still work on these objects you would still need access to that main graph object.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Inversion Of Control](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IoC.aspx) (often abbrieviated IoC). 
It's basically a super object that lets you access other objects whenever and wherever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using inheritance in this scenario.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, which I very well might, but doesn't that work only going to higher levels of classes? I'm mainly wondering about lower?

Comment: This is more like an inverse approach to the problem, using an inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

How will the different controllers control the graph. Generally, objects are passed around the way you have done that -- as method arguments. If an object requires/uses another object (as the contollers control the graphs in your case) across different methods then they are declared to be members of that referring object, as you have done. If they are required for a single method they are passed to the object's specific method as parameters.

If there is a more complex scheme of how the control the graphs in a specific order, you might want to take a look at the [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern.